# How to get output from interpreter.exec() to a file, buffer or a string in java

Tags: java, string, weblogic, wlst

This is my function

```
public void functionWLST() {
  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
  WLSTInterpreter interpreter = WLST.getWLSTInterpreter();
  interpreter.append("connect('weblogic', 'weblogic','t3://localhost:7001')");
  interpreter.exec(buffer.toString());
}
```

Output:

> Successfully connected to Admin Server 'AdminServer' that belongs to domain 'ClassicDomain'.

How can I get the output to a String, file, etc..?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4azrX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be best off using wlst commands. Quoting [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/config_scripting/using_WLST.html#1081491):

> **Redirecting WLST Output to a File**
>
> To start and stop redirecting WLST output to a file, enter:
>
> ```
> redirect(outputFile,[toStdOut])
> stopRedirect()
> ```
>
> You must specify the pathname of the file to which you want to
>   redirect WLST output. You can also optionally specify whether you want
>   WLST output to be sent to stdout; the toStdOut argument defaults to
>   true.
>
> For example, to redirect WLST output to the logs/wlst.log file in the
>   current directory and disable output from being sent to stdout, enter
>   the following command:
>
> ```
> wls:/mydomain/serverConfig> redirect('./logs/wlst.log', 'false')
> ```
>
> For more information, see [redirect](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/config_scripting/reference.html#1155954) and [stopRedirect](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/config_scripting/reference.html#1156524).

If you don't want to do that, you could always pipe the output of the process to a file when running the java process.